# Using wildcard and required operator in an Elasticsearch search

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

We have various rows inside our Elasticsearch index that contain the text

> "... 2% milk ...".

User enters a query like "2% milk" into a search field and we transform it internally to a query

```
title:(+milk* +2%*)
```

because all terms should be required and we are possibly interested into rows that contain "2% milkfat".

This query above return zero hits. Changing the query to

```
title:(+milk* +2%)
```

returns reasonable results. So why does the '*' operator in the first query not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you set a mapping, the "%" sign will get removed in the tokenization process. Basically "2% milk" will get turned into the tokens `2` and `milk`.

When you search for "2%*" it looks for tokens like: `2%`, `2%a`, `2%b`, etc... and not match any indexed tokens, giving no hits.

When you search for "2%", it will go through the same tokenization process as at index-time (you can specify this, but the default tokenization is the same) and you will be looking for documents matching the token `2`, which will give you a hit.

You can [read more about the analysis/tokenization process here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/) and you can set up the analysis you want by [defining a custom mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Prefix and Wildcard queries do not appear to apply the Analyzer to their content.  To provide a few examples:

- `title:(+milk* +2%)` --> `+title:milk* +title:2`
- `title:(+milk* +2%*)` --> `+title:milk* +title:2%*`
- `title:(+milk* +2%3)` --> `+title:milk* +(title:2 title:3)`
- `title:(+milk* +2%3*)` --> `+title:milk* +title:2%3*`
- `+title:super\\-milk` --> `+title:super title:milk`
- `+title:super\\-milk*` --> `+title:super-milk*`

It does make some sense to prevent tokenization of wildcard queries, since wildcard phrase queries are not allowed.  If tokenization were allowed, it would seem to beg the question, especially with embeded wildcards, of just how many terms that wildcard can span.

Comment: Your first line changed `2%` to `2`, so there must be some analysis going on there? Maybe I'm confused...

Comment: Yes, in the first line the `2%` query is not using any wildcards, so is being analyzed.  In the second there is a wildcard attached to it, so there is no analysis done on the field in the one.

Comment: Ah, I see what you meant now... sorry, misunderstanding!